# Can't access File created by paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not sure what's the matter here :

```
file = Rails.root.join(Attachment.last.attachment.url(:original))
# => "/system/attachments/3/original/!my_awesome_pdf.pdf?1359735260"
```

Then I try and do this :

```
File.new(file, 'rb')
# => No such file or directory - /system/attachments/3/original/!my_awesome_pdf.pdf?1359735260
```

Why would that happen? I'm trying to be able to select the file to upload to GroupDocs.com

Comment: Does your awesome.pdf have extenstion .rb ?

Comment: Ah no. It doesn't. But if I remove the extension, or use PDF and swap not using PDF in the name, it still doesn't work either.

Comment: You have much reputation and you're trying to use so strange solution. Probably you should send your file via POST method on GroupDocs.com. Or may be you have another purpose which can solve with more simplier method.

Comment: First I have to be able to access the file though which I can't.

Comment: To note, I can access other files fine within my `system` dir, but anything past attachments won't work. All dirs and files are 777.

Answer (score 0):

Ah the problem was that URI's will throw off Ruby from recognizing the name of the file. Removing the URI allows Ruby to open the file.